# Kendo UI Sticky/Fixed/Floated Header disturbing the overall structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```js
 function CustomizeGrid() {
        debugger;
          var wrapper = this.wrapper,
              header = wrapper.find(".k-grid-header");

          function resizeFixed() {
              var paddingRight = parseInt(header.css("padding-right"));
              header.css("width", wrapper.width() - paddingRight);
          }

          function scrollFixed() {
              var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
                  tableOffsetTop = wrapper.offset().top,
                  tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + wrapper.height() - header.height();
              if(offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom) {
                  header.removeClass("fixed-header");
              } else if(offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && !header.hasClass("fixed")) {
                  header.addClass("fixed-header");
              }
          }

          resizeFixed();
          $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
          $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
      }
```

```css
/*sticky header*/
 .fixed-header {
        top:46px;
        position:fixed;
        width:auto;
        z-index: 100000;
      }

      .scrollMore {
        margin-top:600px;
      }

      .up {
        cursor:pointer;
      }
    @@media screen and (max-width: 1130px) {
        .fixed-header {
            top: 91px;
        }
    }
    @@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
        .fixed-header {
            top: 0px;
        }
    }
```

CustomizeGrid() add/remove the class and update the offset value on scroll and resize.
the problem is that the structure of kendo grid got disturbed.If I click on refresh button the Kendo adjust himself well.

Now the problem is that Customize grid only function when called on data bound of kendo, and refresh() fires the data bound event again.
So I cant add the refresh code with in these methods because it creates a loop.

I just want to Refresh(only once) the grid after this Customize method finishes its operation.

Comment: Kendo grid is rendered through Razor Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this `AdjustGrid()` method on grid load and window resize event. Assign offset according to your header footer heights.

This fiction will keep the grid size according to the available area on screen so that you can scroll while headers are visible.

```css
var offset=$("#header").height()+$("#footer").height();

function AdjustGrid() {
        $.each($(".k-grid-content > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(2), .k-grid-content-locked > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(2)"), function (i, item) {
            item.parentElement.parentElement.id = "adjustableGridContent";
            $('#adjustableGridContent').css("height", "auto");
            if ($('#adjustableGridContent').height() > ($(window).height() - offset))
                $('#adjustableGridContent').css("height", $(window).height() - (offset+30) + "px");
            /*you can add your custom code according to your design*/
 });
            item.parentElement.parentElement.id = "";
        });
    }
```